# Windows: Changing an External Hard Drive's Drive Letter

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, external-hard-drive, drive-letter

I'm trying to resolve a file path error problem with TortoiseSVN [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810761/using-tortoisesvn-from-multiple-computers-with-an-svn-repo-on-external-hard-drive) on Stack Overflow. One of the answers suggested trying to change the drive letter of my external hard drive. **How can I change the drive letter for a USB device?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually put this on SO for you :)

But here goes again: You can use Window's Disk Management Utility.  Just right-click the drive and change Drive Letter IIRC.

Comment: Oh, whoops, didn't notice. Thanks! Going to trying it now.

Comment: No worries.  Hope it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to computer management (Right click Computer / My Computer), then click "Manage"

"Expand Storage" > "Disk Management", and right click on the drive you wish to change.

Click on "Change Drive Letter and Paths" then first remove the existing map followed by adding a new one.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **[USB Drive Letter Manager for Windows](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html)**

> USBDLM is a Windows service that gives
>   you control over Window's drive letter
>   assignment for USB drives. Running as
>   service makes it independent of user
>   privileges, so there is no need to
>   give the users the privilege to change
>   drive letters.
>
> It automatically solves conflicts
>   between USB drives and network or
>   subst drives of the currently logged
>   on user.
>
> Furthermore you can define new default
>   letters for USB drives and much more.

*USBDLM is freeware.*

p.s.: USBDLM is a REAL blessing if you have a lot of USB drives to manage!