# Windows 10 change drive letter hangs

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am trying to change the letter of an external USB drive from F: to G:. I have tried using the Disk Management utility to do this, similar to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/76169/280046). When I click "OK" for the final step, the cursor changes to the "progress spinner" and stays that way for as long as I've cared to wait.

I am able to access and use the drive normally, so it appears to be basically fine. I just need to use a different letter so that my backup software doesn't lose its mind.

I have tried rebooting into Safe Mode, but I get the same results.

Maybe related: if I try to "Safely Remove" the drive it also seems to hang forever.

So, how do I diagnose & resolve this hang, or change my drive letter some other way?

Comment: Nope, there is no G: drive showing, in either Disk Management or diskpart's `list volume` command

Comment: Try to change driver letter with `diskpart` command.

Comment: `select volume 7`, then `assign letter=g` has been hanging for several minutes now. Seems like the same behavior.

Comment: First, **completely** shut down the computer (or Restart), so that the drive may be safely removed. Then, on reboot, you should be able to insert it and assign any *unused* drive letter. See https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-a-drive-letter-2626069

Comment: I have restarted the machine multiple times, including into safe mode.

Comment: I built a brand new computer from the ground up with all new components, installed a fresh Windows 10 from scratch, and I'm having the exact same behavior with this external drive. Literally the only common component is the drive itself. Only difference is that it was auto-assigned D:, but I can't rename it all. FFS Windows.